# Connecting to Sage 50 database using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sage-erp, sage50

I want to append a secondary invoice number to the invoice number generated by Sage 50. I want a new number to be generated automatically and appended to the primary number. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sage 50 doesn't use SQL for its data so this isn't possible. Do you need to store it somewhere in Sage? If not you could do something with the Sage report designer.